# How to find the minimum of list with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have got a list containing a value and numpy array like

```
    arr = [(0.5, array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (1.2, array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  
    0.,  0.])), (3.5, array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]))]
```

How can I find the minimum value just based on the first value of each list item. The desired output should be

```
   result = (0.5, array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]))
```

because 0.5 is less than 1,2 and 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, use `min`. It gives you the minimum.

---

If there will ever be duplicates in the integer, you'll want to use `min` with a key:

```
min(arr, key=lambda num_ar: num_ar[0])
```

in order to avoid it falling back on comparing the second item.

Comment: When I use min it tells me ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You should probably have added what you've tried to the question before you ask it. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer.